# SQL Data truncation error: SQL Warning Code: 1406 . Data truncation: Data too long for column 'contents' at row 1

Tags: mysql, sql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Data JPA repository services and I have written a custom query which inserts data into the table.

My table structure:-

**desc Person;**

```
+------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+--------------+
| Field                  | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                     | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| status                 | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| message                | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| contents               | LONGTEXT     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |     
+------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

My query is something like this:

```
UPDATE Person ps
    set ps.status ='FAILED',
        ps.message='ok'
    where ps.id = 6;
```

I am not even trying to update the column named "contents". But still i am getting Data too long for column "contents" column. What am I doing wrong here ?

I have checked the max_allowed packet size(1GB) and datatype of column (longtext).

**EDIT**:
My code is something like this:-

```
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Integer> {

@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
@Transactional(readOnly=false)
@Query(UPDATE Person ps set ps.status =:STATUS,ps.message=:MESSAGE where ps.id =:ID)
int updatePersonForId(@Param("STATUS") String status,@Param("MESSAGE") String message,@Param("ID") int id);
}
```

Comment: is there a trigger on that table?

Comment: Juergen, I have a trigger. But i am not updating "contents" field in that

Comment: @KiranKulkarni: What operation did trigger the posted error? Check if there is an `insert` or `update` event took place.

Comment: @RavinderReddy, I got the error after update query in the question. But, it is triggered throug' Spring jpa data rest service

Comment: is this the query you were trying to execute or the query you found in the log file?

Comment: @e4c5 I have updated my question with the Java code . There is no query printed in the log. In log, I am able to see just the exception

Comment: I am not speaking of any logging in your application but of the mysql error log. That shows the exact query that produces the error.